# Oracle delete row using sequence number

Tags: oracle, row, sequence, delete-row, sql-delete

My DB knowledge is quite limited and I am trying to delete a row with the following query:

DELETE FROM *table*
WHERE *column* in (select *sequence*.CURRVAL FROM DUAL);

This is used in a .sql to clean up the database after integration tests are run in Maven. I have Googled it but still haven't found an answer for the delete statement to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Surely you'd find the largest value (if the sequence is incremented) of the column updated by the sequence, and then update or delete the records that had that value? Also, never assume that the internal sequence CURRVAL is what you think it is!

Comment: @DBMarcos99 - my DB is in an inconsistent state. I cannot use max(column) and assume it is equal to sequence.CURRVAL - I do need to use CURRVAL to delete the record. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a CURRVAL in a DELETE statement, as you can read here: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287

But since you are using SQL scripts, you can do it like this in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create table t( id number);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> insert into t (id) values (seq.nextval);

1 row created.

SQL> column i new_value curseqval
SQL> select seq.currval i from dual;

         I
----------
         1

1 row selected.

SQL> delete from t where id = &curseqval;
old   1: delete from t where id = &curseqval
new   1: delete from t where id =          1

1 row deleted.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: could you please explain the snippet:
column i new_value curseqval

Comment: Sure. Please see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#i2674387. It assigns the outcome of column i to substitution variable curseqval.

Answer (score 2):

1) sequence.CURRVAL from DUAL is a single discrete value; the use of IN is inappropriate

2) because you are referencing *sequence*.CURRVAL you need not use a subquery, you may access this value directly.

try:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column = sequence.CURRVAL;
```

*assuming* the sequence is being used as a primary key (somewhere) this will result in the deletion of the most recently insert key record or if the column is a foreign key, then only those records that are related to the most recent record.

**oops...**
I've done enough delete queries that I didn't check my work. While I have never thought to use sequence values in a delete it never occurred to me that you *couldn't* do it.

this, however will work:

```
declare del_key number;
begin
select  seq_so_test.currval into del_key from dual;
delete from t_so_test where id = del_key;
 end;
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me on oracle 10g. Do you try this oneself?  `create table t( id number);
create sequence seq;
insert into t (id) values (seq.nextval);
delete from t where id = seq.currval;`

Comment: your code snippet unfortunatelly does not work, this is what Oracle 11g replies:
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here [Error Code: 2287] [SQL State: 42000]
-- to complicate matters, my DB is in an inconsistent state. I cannot use max(column) and assume it is equal to sequence.CURRVAL - I do need to use CURRVAL to delete the record. How do I do this?

Comment: @schurik & @Pomario, revised per your findings. At least for 10g (my current verison)